# how many spacers do I need for a 83mm bottom bracket and a 142x10 hub?

Tags: shimano, bottom-bracket, crankset, downhill

I have a Zee crankset on a 83mm bottom bracket (downhill bike). The [Shimano manual](http://bike.shimano.com.sg/publish/content/global_cycle/en/sg/index/tech_support/tech_tips.download.-Par50rparsys-0003-downloadFile.html/Hollowtech%2520II%2520Crank%2520Installation.pdf+hollowtech+2&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh5h31__eUEAwl82s5zZJbDL2vJetuGp5JzrgJrx6HRlx28r0OBKaY-O1w2mpfwFkn-au9TAOVI_ITp8JKvokm8YlevJ8pKEyLuegTwSw6TrnMiI8uWXR7I18FOHdKiU1JZEPC0&sig=AHIEtbSMsrmu3-42CWAoTOyn7oDDtGw6YQ) says to use two 2.5mm spacers on the drive side, and one 2.5mm spacer on the non-drive side. However, this presumes the rear hub has a 150mm spacing, typical for downhill bikes. My bike has a 142x10 hub, when I use the spacers as specified, the chainline is completely off, I can't even get the chain on the largest cog. Since I'm not using a 150mm hub I obviously need to change the spacers, but I have no idea how to figure out how many spacers of what size I need on each side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far are chainring spacers: http://sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html

Answer (score 1):

83mm bottom brackets were designed specifically for use with a 150mm rear dropout width. You would be able to shim the bottom bracket across 5mm to bring it to where it would sit on a 73mm bb to align the chain line but you would be pushing your non drive out 10mm which would have an anatomical impact on the rider. This is a significant amount of q-factor imbalance and could quick become an uncomfortable bike to ride.

The simplest solution is to swap the crankset for a 73mm version.

Comment: It's possible to use a 73mm crankset with a 83mm bb? Don't know if the imbalanced q-factor would be noticable on a DH bike, where there isn't any uphill pedalling?

Comment: Sorry didn't pick up that it was a 83mm bb shell, thought you were asking about 83mm crank shimmed out on a 73mm shell. Whats the bike? I've not heard of anything with a 83mm shell having a 142mm dropout? Any off balance that much could throw balance off. Its a bodge anyway, not ideal.

Comment: Chainline difference is going to be 7.5mm between a 83mm 1x and a 68/73 mm 1x. 7.5mm is quite large, what about swapping 1 of the 2 spacers on the drive side to the non-drive side to reduce it to 5mm and try that?

Comment: It's a Banshee Darkside with swappable dropouts, I choose the 142x10 because those are the wheels I had. Didn't know I was getting myself into trouble :) I'd figure they would know how to build it but the designer didn't seem to know the correct answer himself (http://forums.mtbr.com/banshee-bikes/official-darkside-thread-869617-11.html#post11294809). Indeed, I'll try swapping

Comment: Nice bike, hope you get it sorted.